# Does Django ORM support ternary associations (relationship between three models)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Does Django support using associations in which participates three models ? eg :

- User
- Project
- Group

a User is a participant of a project using a role (group).

How to handle such associations using Django ORM since it's never mentioned on the official documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, the question it's quite ambiguous, but you can navigate as many relations you want using double underscore.
For example to know if user it's linked to the project:

```
if User.objects.filter(group__project=Project).exists():
    # User works on Project
```

More documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use intermediate model with a foreign key as extra field.

Comment: You can use manyToMany relations with a through model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany